# 'Foreground' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(Foreground).(0)'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF canvas project where I drag and drop objects on the canvas from a toolbox. Based upon certain data, some of those objects should flash or blink.  I get an unhandled exception :Cannot animate '(Foreground).(0)' on an immutable object instance.. Following is my code. Somebody suggested using (Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color) and I changed that in my markup but it doesn't seem to fix it.

```
<!-- DataTemplate for DesignerCanvas look and feel -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SingleValueControlViewModel}">
    <Grid>

        <Label Name="label" Content="{Binding TagValue}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Height="{Binding ItemHeight}" Width="{Binding ItemWidth}" 
          Background="{Binding BackColor}"     
          Foreground="{Binding ForeColor}"
          BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor}"
          BorderThickness="{Binding StyleProperties.BorderWidth}"
          FontFamily="{Binding StyleProperties.Font.FontFamily}"
          FontSize = "{Binding StyleProperties.Font.Size}"
          FontStyle="{Binding StyleProperties.Font.Style}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding TextAlign}" >
<Label.Style>
              <Style>
                  <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StyleProperties.FlashEnable}" Value="true">
                          <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                          <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                  <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                          Duration="00:00:00:01"
                                          From="Black" To="Red">
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                  </Storyboard>
                              </BeginStoryboard>
                          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                      </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
          </Label.Style>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: flash ? what do you mean by 'some of those objects should flash'. are these objects will contain flash movie ? or will they appear differently like glowing etc.

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: @user3798700 I got your point, will post answer, am working on it.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I modified my original question with the updated code and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* Final answer after examining user's code
*/

Add this to your DiagramControl.xaml

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">                                                         
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To=" 0.1" Duration="00:00:0.3"/>
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>                                                
</DataTrigger>
```

/* Fresh update as user still can't run his animation and reports error said in comment
*/

You must be binding your Background, Foreground properties, and remember Brush objects are immutable. There is a workaround as described in following msdn link :

[immutable instance animation error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/26/cannotanimateimmutableobjectinstance.aspx)

[debugging animations](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebuggingAnimations.html)

/* New answer posted after user updated his question with present XAML code */

I have used your code as it is like below with one addition of TargetType="Label" and it is working perfectly. I used my own StyleProperties.FlashEnable binding for your DataTrigger to work.

This is one side. Another side : You are doing all this dynamically as you are dragging items to Canvas. For this you need to apply your style/triggers in code.

```
<Grid>
<Label Content="Hi ! I am added dynamically" TextBlock.FontSize="45">
  <Label.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StyleProperties.FlashEnable, Mode=OneWay}" Value="true">
         <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
         <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
         <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
               <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                 <ColorAnimation 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                     Duration="00:00:00:01"
                     From="Black" To="Red">
                  </ColorAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
             </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      </DataTrigger>                        
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
  </Label.Style>
</Label>
</Grid>
```

/* Old answer posted before user updated his question */
To show your object flashing, you must be changing their Foreground property. And this Foreground color must be coming from some variable. For binding you have to use a dependency property, or your class containing your property/variable must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so that your property raise PropertyChanged event.

You should also provide some initial value to Foreground if you are using Animation.

You also might be using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource.

More can be said if you post some XAML.

Comment: Still get the same error - Cannot animate '(Foreground).(0)' on an immutable object instance. I am binding the background and foreground colors before the style. Do you think that is what is causing it to not work ?

Comment: @user3798700 r u there ?

Comment: I tried with the converter and it gave the same error. I then deleted the bindings outside of the style and it still gave me the same error. At this point, I might just write a timer thread to make it visible and non visible to mimic blinking.

Comment: @user3798700 may be you post a workable sample on dropbox.com, or i can see with team viewer

Comment: Here is the dropbox link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjr7wvdi7mnyaud/DiagramDesignerMVVMOct7.zip?dl=0 . The viewmodel in question is SingleValueControlViewModel and the xaml for the data template is SingleValueControlDataTemplate . Let me know if you have any questions. I stripped out most functionality to keep it a simple UI.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlashEnable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                            Duration="0:0:1" From="Black" To="Red">
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can also explicitly set a SolidColorBrush in the style setter of the Foreground property:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlashEnable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ColorAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color"
                            Duration="0:0:1" From="Black" To="Red">
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but get error -  Cannot animate '(Foreground).(0)' on an immutable object instance. I also updated the xaml so that storyboard.targetproperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" but I still get the same error.

Comment: This is inside my datatemplate. When I paste your code it says the property Content is set more than once. I'm going to edit my original post to include the complete xaml. I apologize for not putting the complete code out there. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Probably a copy and paste error. Just replace your Style by the Style from my answer.

Comment: Same error - Cannot animate 'Foreground.Color' on an immutable object instance.  :(